# Does it make sense for a dimension to also be a metric

Tags: database-design, google-analytics, analytics, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm currently working on a warehouse schema roughly utilising a Dimensional Modelling approach.

The general ideas is to have a single facts table, full of event-metrics of interest, at the lowest level of granularity. Along with this, of course will be a dimensional table(a) where dimensions of the event being recorded will be kept. These tables are tied by a `dimension_id`.

My question is: is it possible, or rather does it make sense, for something to be both a dimension and a metric.

An example would perhaps be the position of a *product* in some search results. The position of a given product can be considered a metric; users may wish to run the following query for a product:

*What's the average position that products with dimension x = y were shown in last week?*

At the same time, *position* could itself be considered a dimension:

*Show me the click-through rate of all products with position = 2 for the last month*

What's the right way to tackle something like this ina data warehouse (we're looking at column-oriented solutions if that makes a difference).

Comment: Do you mean "measure"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in both cases you are just running a query on the measure in the fact

> products with position = 2 for the last month

Thinking about the methods for generating this, this can be derived by generating the correct list of products out of the fact table on the fly, then limiting your outer fact query to these products.

This is fine if you have a capable analyst running custom SQL but it's a lot more difficult for a non technical analyst to build this in any reporting tool that I've ever used.

OR

you can 'harden' your position as an attribute into a slowly changing dimension. But for fast changing data this is usually not an option... as your dimension changes so fast it's impractical.

If you could tie your required anlysis period down to a month, it might be practical to implement the monthly rating (and many other attributes including rolling period type attributes) into a slowly changing dimension, which would mean you would have at least twelve product dimension members per year, but you boil every concievable realtive KPI into a column in the dimension, which is usually very helpful.

But I'm guessing this isn't anything new to you.

Comment: I guess my question is more — do you duplicate some piece of information (position), by storing both in the fact table as a metric, and a dimension table as an attribute, or do you adjust your reporting systems to allow for aggregation queries on numerical dimensions. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: The way I see it, a batch loaded dimensional warehouse gives you the luxury of duplicating all kinds of information for convenience and speed.